# How to get address (street) using C#?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm executing my query and it works fine when I'm using the following *ColumnSet*.

```
...
ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(
  "name", 
  "address1_postalcode",
  "beep_cin",
  "telephone1",
  //"address1_street1", 
  "address1_city"),
...
```

However, when I uncomment the street reference, I get an error telling me that such an attribute doesn't exist. I'm guessing it's got to do with the control being composite.

1. How can I access in CRM 2013 the equivalent of *address1_street1* in CRM 2011?
2. Why can I access the other *address_...* fields like I'm used to but not *street1*?

## Edit

I discovered also that even on the client, using JavaScript, there seems to be something weird. Let's try to run the following two lines (*frames[0]* is there because that's how it works in IE console window, <kbd>F12</kbd>).

```
frames[0].Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_street1").getValue()
frames[0].Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_city").getValue()
```

While the first one gives me *Stockholm*, the seconds yields an error because the returned attribute is *null*, despite the fact that I've entered the street as supposed to. Furthermore, I notice that the following line:

```
frames[0].Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_composite").getValue()
```

returns the whole composite address text - street, city, country etc. In that attribute, there's an object called *controls* but I didn't find anything useful in it. This is weird and unexpected. I don't like the combination of weirdness and unexpectedness.

Please note that it's the CRM13 version that the weirdification occurs in.

Of course, I could use [this atrocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481581.aspx) below but is that really what we want to see on the screen of every CRM developer?! It makes my eyes bleed and my will to live withers.

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line1")
```

Besides, I still don't get the value and I still can't see how to use it in C#!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which entity you want to retrieve, but normally the logical name for `Address 1: Street1` field is `address1_line1`

Here the Attribute Metadata for Account entity:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328057(v=crm.5).aspx#bkmk_attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328057%28v=crm.5%29.aspx#bkmk_attributes)

Comment: You're up for a gotcha, I believe. Try to run the two lines I added to my original post on an instance of *Account*.

Comment: I tried your frames[0] javascript lines, with `address1_street1` I get the error `Unable to get value of the property 'getValue': object is null or undefined` but with `address1_line1` and `address1_city` I get the form values. Inside account the field name is `address1_line1` for JavaScript and C#

Comment: Oh... **LINE1** not **STREET1**! I should be shot. Twice. Then stoned and kicked. I guess the sleep depravation is getting to me. Here I'm crying with my head in my sitting device swearing at the stupid CRM... You're a savior!